# how to represent a variable with other variables given a equation set in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I tried to eliminate r and z from the equation set and get the expression of S without r and z:

[image]

```
var('xi R R_bfs k S z r')
solve(r**2 - 2*R*z + (k + 1)*z**2, S*cos(xi)+z-R_bfs, S*sin(xi)-r, S, r, z)
```

This returns an empty list for S, but I am sure there is solution for s. Is there any method or function to handle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

When I run into problems like this I try to use the CAS to do the steps for me that lead to the solution that I want. With only 3 equations this is pretty straightforward.

We can eliminate S from the last 2 equations

```
>>> eqs = r**2 - 2*R*z + (k + 1)*z**2, S*cos(xi)+z-R_bfs, S*sin(xi)-r
>>> solve(eqs[1:],(r,z))
{r: S*sin(xi), z: R_bfs - S*cos(xi)}
```

This solution can be substituted into the first equation

```
>>> e1 = eqs[0].subs(_)
```

This results in a polynomial in S, of degree = 2, that does not contain r or z

```
>>> degree(e1, S)
2
>>> e1.has(r, z)
False
```

And the solutions of a general quadratic are

```
>>> q = solve(a*x**2 + b*x + c, x); q
[(-b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a), -(b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a)]
```

So all we need are the values of a, b and c from e1 and we should have our
solutions for S, free or r and z:

```
>>> A, B, C = Poly(e1, S).all_coeffs()
>>> solns = [i.subs({a: A, b: B, c: C}) for i in q]
```

Before we look at those, let's let cse remove common expressions

```
>>> reps, sols = cse(solns)
```

Here are the replacements that are identified

```
>>> for i in reps:
...     print(i)
(x0, cos(xi))
(x1, x0**2)
(x2, k*x1 + x1 + sin(xi)**2)
(x3, 1/(2*x2))
(x4, 2*R)
(x5, x0*x4)
(x6, 2*R_bfs*x0)
(x7, k*x6)
(x8, x5 - x6 - x7)
(x9, R_bfs**2)
(x10, sqrt(-4*x2*(-R_bfs*x4 + k*x9 + x9) + x8**2))
```

And in terms of those, here are the solutions:

```
>>> for i in sols:
...     print(i)
x3*(x10 - x5 + x6 + x7)
-x3*(x10 + x8)
```

If you prefer the non-cse form, you can look at that, too. Here is one solution:

```
>>> print(filldedent(solns[0]))

(-2*R*cos(xi) + 2*R_bfs*k*cos(xi) + 2*R_bfs*cos(xi) +
sqrt(-4*(-2*R*R_bfs + R_bfs**2*k + R_bfs**2)*(k*cos(xi)**2 +
sin(xi)**2 + cos(xi)**2) + (2*R*cos(xi) - 2*R_bfs*k*cos(xi) -
2*R_bfs*cos(xi))**2))/(2*(k*cos(xi)**2 + sin(xi)**2 + cos(xi)**2))
```

If your initial all-in-one-go solution fails, try to let SymPy be your Swiss Army Knife :-)